# Want to have a new build in Jenkins at every CVS changes, but not more than one build every two days

Tags: build, jenkins, schedule

how to schedule to meet this requirement?

1. If there is a previous build in last two days, and comes a change in CVS, then the next build will be started two days later from the previous build
2. If there comes a change in CVS, and the previous build finished before two days ago, start this build immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your need requires a custom, "smart" trigger for the build.

I have a similar need, and I use the Jenkins [ScriptTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) plugin to execute a "smart" shell script that will evaluate the conditions and decide if to start a build or not.

Example logic in script:

1. Check if two days have passed from last build
2. If so, check if there was also a change in VCS compared to last build
3. If so, exit 0, and allow build to start

I hope this helps.